# akka stream flatMapMerge of any breadth

Tags: akka-stream

```
Source.unfold(0)(n => Some(n+1, ('A'+ n % 26).toChar))
  .flatMapConcat( c => Source.unfold(1)(n => Some((n+1, s"$c$n"))) )
  .runForeach(println)
```

This prints only elements from the first sub stream: `A1, A2, A3, ...`
That's because `flatMapConcat` consumes the sub streams in order.

There is a `flatMapMerge` function that can consume elements from a fixed number of sub streams.

Is there a more general `flatMapMerge` that can pick any available elements from any of the sub stream ? Something similar to the merge function that outputs elements from any of its upstreams.

If not how would you implement one?

Answer (score 2):

Note the `breadth` parameters needed by `flatMapMerge` does not limit the amount of substreams that are merged, it does limit the amount of substreams that are merged *in parallel*.

If you want to merge any number of substreams in parallel you can always use `.flatMapMerge(Int.MaxValue, ???)`.